# Geoserver dxf plugin - How to export attributes labels?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, dxf

I'm trying to export from Geoserver a set of layers with WFS request and dxf plugin for dxf conversion.

There is an option **withattributes:true** that I have added for each vector layer a LAYERNAME_attributes, but I don't know how to display labels in my dxf drawing.

I want to see street names, numbers.... and so on

Here is my [example](http://geoserver-t.comune.modena.it/geoserver/modena_local/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=modena_local:ferrovie,modena_local:verde,modena_local:edifici,modena_local:aste,modena_local:strade_principali,modena_local:civici,modena_local:cn_conf_10_14&cql_filter=within%28the_geom,%20querySingle%28%27modena_local:cn_conf_10_14%27,%20%27the_geom%27,%27FOGLIO=31%27%29%29&format_options=withattributes:true;colors:7,3,1;asblock=false&outputformat=dxf)

I have attached an image showing the file loaded in DraftSight a CAD software

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the annotation tools to create labels.  Since you have included your attributes, you should be able to select the label tool in the annotation tools (in your CAD software) and then select the feature you want to label.  The attribute should come through for the label.  You're not likely to be able to label everything at once.  CAD software works much differently that GIS software.  Labels are produced as features, just like lines or points.  If they don't exist, you will have to create them.  They are classed as annotations.